# Problem with Wallet Creation, signature error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to create a wallet for new rest api server, but whenever I call code to generate new Wallet I'm getting error like
"Decoding SignatureHeader failed: Error illegal buffer ..."
Here is screen shot of my code, it is taken from virtual machine
[image]

I'm using hyperledger fabric 2.2 and run under the fabric-samples/test-network
I was clone this [HyperledgerFabroc](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples)

Here is also print screen of the error:
[image]

I would appreciate if someone can navigate me how to manage successfully to create a wallet ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks to be occurring within a chaincode transaction function. You should not be using the client SDK to do a transaction invocation from within chaincode. Instead look to use the `invokeChaincode` function on the stub:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-1.4/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#invokeChaincode